# Pset 2 CS50 Substitution Problem, If statement assigns variables(i guess)

Tags: c, cs50, substitution

I created a code for pset2 problem, named substitution in C.

The programs takes an String of Characters in command-line and apply it to a given text and changes it, printing the ciphertext.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    //First part, checks KEY input

    if (argc != 2)  // checks quantity of command-line arguments
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution KEY\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int largo = strlen(argv[1]);

    while (i < largo) //checks if char are alphabetic
    {
        if (isalpha(argv[1][i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Key must contain only alphabetic characters\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else //changes to uppercase
        {
            argv[1][i] = toupper(argv[1][i]);
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (i != 26)  //checks length of Key
    {
        printf("Key must be 26 characters long\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < largo - 1; ++j) //checks repetition of characters
    {

        for (int k = j + 1; k < largo; ++k)
        {

            if (argv[1][j] == argv[1][k])
            {
                printf("Key must not have duplicated characters\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    //second part asks for input

    //declaration of strings to get and transform

    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext:");
    string alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    string ciphertext = plaintext;

    //third part: cifrado

    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(plaintext); ++x)
    {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[x]) != 0)
        {
            int lower = 0;
            if (islower(plaintext[x]) != 0) // is lower case?
            {
                lower = 1;
                plaintext[x] = toupper(plaintext[x]);
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < strlen(alfabeto); ++y)
            {
                //printf("alfa: %c   text: %c\n", alfabeto[y], plaintext[x]);

                if (alfabeto[y] == plaintext[x])
                {
                    ciphertext[x] = argv[1][y];
                    //printf("c: %s\n", ciphertext);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (lower == 1)
            {
                ciphertext[x] = tolower(ciphertext[x]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s", ciphertext);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that the last if statement, kind of assigns the character in "ciphertext" to the "plaintext" variable, so i had to put a break statement in it, to stop that.

Any guesses why this program doesn't work as intended when there's no "break" statement?

```
                if (alfabeto[y] == plaintext[x])
                {
                    ciphertext[x] = argv[1][y];
                    //printf("c: %s\n", ciphertext);
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: `string ciphertext = plaintext;` Both pointers point to the same string. You need to make a copy of the string.

Comment: `string ciphertext = strdup(plaintext);`

Comment: So, asigning a string to another variable doesn't copy that string? instead it creates 2 variables that access to the same locations in memory?

Thank you, by the way.

Comment: Yes, because the CS50 `string` type is just `char *`, so you're just assigning pointers.